# Google search syntax: urls which end with given word

Tags: google-search

Is it possible to formulate google search query so it will search for urls ending with specified word?

For instance, I want to find all urls with title "news" ending with ".php". I've tried this:

```
intitle:news inurl:.php
```

but it gives me urls like "www.phpdeveloper.org" as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the workarounds, is using "filetype:" operator:

```
intitle:news filetype:php
```

It will give links like "hiphop.start.bg/link.php?id=264549" as well, but it is much better than nothing.